# Old Servlet content keeps persistent in html

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am learning `Servlet` and `JSP` using `Apache Tomcat`.
Here I have a simple Java class extending `HttpServlet` and put some string on `HTML`.
It works except that the first text message is persistent even if I modified it.

```
package com.example.tutorial;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello, Java."); 
    }
}
```

First I saw `"Hello, Java"` in

```
http://localhost:8080/.../example
```

I changed the string to `"Goodbye"`  but still saw `"Hello, Java"`.

I tried to restart Tomcat and Eclipse but that won't solve the problem. Is there any cache in Tomcat?

Help me out of this, please.

Comment: Are you sure you have recompiled the servlet class and that Tomcat has reloaded the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

Make sure that

```
Project > Build Automatically
```

is enabled.

Make sure that auto publishing to the server you are using is enabled, for that you can proceed like this:

Go to

```
Window > Show View > Servers
```

when the `Servers` tab is displayed, double click on your server to open its configuration. In the drop down menu `Publishing` choose `Automatically publish when resources change` save and restart the server

```
right click on your server > Restart
```

Clean the work directory of Tomcat, on the Servers tab

```
right click on your server > Clean Tomcat Work Directory...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are so helpful to newbie like me.